# Setting the default c++ and c compiler in osx 10.9.1

Tags: c++, ios, macos, cmake

I am trying to run a cmake script from terminal and it picks the CXX and C compiler as clang 5.0.0 whereas I want the default compiler to be GNU. How can you set the path variables or settings for doing this? Thanks in advance

Comment: This is really a cmake question - you can override the default toolchain on the command-line.  As to whether any recent install of XCode actually has GCC included, that's another matter.  It's been deprecated in favour of clang, and before then was stuck at the archaic gcc-lvm 4.2.  Have you got some really specific reason to be using GCC in the first place?

Comment: Actually, I have been trying to install opencv on xcode for iOS development but the build returns the following errors in the terminal: 
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 5.0.0
-- The C compiler identification is Clang 5.0.0
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - failed
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
I am just trying different ways to solve this freakin' issue

Comment: I seem to remember this being a nightmare last time I used OpenCV. I managed to find binary installers - although 32-bit only. Not a lot of good if you want to hack on OpenCV itself.